# IIS6 shows out of memory error - Error show is the same URL repeated many times in event log

Tags: iis-6, memory, internet-explorer, asp.net

I have an HTTPS ASPX based web site that is generating out of memory errors under load.  The errors seem to coincide with what shows in the event log as a series of the same URL repeated many times such as https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2https://servername/virtual/aspxpage.aspx?param1=data1&param2=data2 etc. The end result is greater than 16,000 characters of URL attempting to be passed to the web server.

Environment:
IIS6, Windows Server 2003, IE6

Answer (score 0):

So:

- Your error page is throwing an error
- which is getting passed to the error page

See where I'm going with that?

Alternatively, it's as possible that you've a code branch that introduces recursion or a syntactic error in the URL within a non-error page; it looks like you could check the input parameters fairly easily and avoid this.

The out of memory error is probably triggered by that, but the original error's probably something else.

Consider adding a couple of try/catch statements to the error handler, or attach a debugger, figure out what exception's being thrown, and handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks very much for your thoughts on this.  As additional information, the URL which is repeated is not the complete URL as generated by the code.  The full URL when entered directly to the browser works just fine. I will check the error logs and error checking and post further issues / comments.